# Views Always Doing an HTTP GET instead of a Post on Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've not been able to figure out why this is happening. On each simple view that I am on, when I click the submit button, the request is always getting routed back to the controller and firing off the view's HTTPGET method. I have even tried hard-coding the form tag with a "POST", but it's still occurring. It appears to be some sort of routing issue, but I'm not sure where to look next. The application consists a public section and then two "areas" (admin and agency). I am having this issue in both "areas." Any ideas what the problem could be? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oops. After looking at earlier today and not being able to figure out the issue, I had a form tag opening and closing on my Layout page. This was causing the undesired behavior.

Comment: Always look on the generated html when you face a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "a form tag opening and closing"? Isn't there supposed to be an opening form tag and closing tag? Was it an extraneous one?