# HTML form send data by GET instead POST

Tags: html, post, get

It is very strangely, but my HTML form send data via GET, not POST.

```
    <form name="mistake" action="http://web-server.com:8888/WebApp/Email/Create" method=post>
  <input type="text" name="url" size="50" readonly="readonly">
          <br />
          <span class="text">
          Error :
          </span>
          <br /> 
          <textarea rows="5" name="mis" cols="37" readonly="readonly"></textarea> 
          <br />
          <span class="text">
          Comment :
          </span>
          <br /> 
          <textarea rows="5" name="comment" cols="37"></textarea> 
          
          <input type="hidden" name="email" value="admin@admin.com">
          <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Errors">
          <div style="margin-top: 7px"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
          <input onclick="hide()" type="button" value="Close" id="close" name="close"> 
          </div>
</form>
```

I test it on IE10 with standart options.
*HTML form very simple and i write only little example of code.* 
How to fix it? 
Thank you!

P.S. Change URL. This URL [web-server.com:8888/WebApp/Email/Create](http://web-server.com:8888/WebApp/Email/Create) - belongs to asp mvc app.

When i run my web app and ths static site on local machine- it works.
But when i runs static page on local machine- and mvc on server- it not works.

P.P.S.- this variant of form- is origine (i cut some tags). Now it is origine.

I dont why, but it works. May be - problem on server side?

Comment: Unless you are doing something dynamic with JavaScript, it should use POST. (Also, do make sure to include valid HTML - in this case at least the form closing tag is missing; and a fiddle test-case goes a long way in reproducing the claimed behavior.)

Comment: Do you have defined the `hide()` function.

Comment: I think something in `hide()` function avoiding the page from posting.

Comment: hide() function defined (i dont know where, but when hide() runs- form closes.

Comment: Is it something similar to this question (I see in your example you are missing </form>):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653893/views-always-doing-an-http-get-instead-of-a-post-on-submit

Comment: What is different about the page when you are running server locally compared to on the server? Can you paste this exact snippet of code into a file and open in browser - do you get a post or get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be a post (assuming that you forgot the closing  tag only in your example). I added your code and put the closing  tag in an html file and submitted in Chrome. This is what I see in the network trace:

[image]

Also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8653893/746754) in case you are doing the same.

Comment: I agree with the "should be a post". I believe the OP is hiding something (in `hide` even).

Comment: @user2864740 - agree, it is something like that.

Answer (score 25):

The problem is rather common and the answer quite elusive:

Somewhere in your code you have an orphaned `<form>`. This means that the next form is nested in the previous one, and its method is ignored. Delete or close the superfluous `<form>` and you are done.

Answer (score 5):

A web application framework I am using automatically redirects POST requests for the action URL to the same URL with a trailing slash.  HTTP redirection downgrades POST to GET.

Comment: @AdmiralLand I forgot how I got a similar puzzle.  My trying to reproduce showed the redirection in a contrived example where a flask server route ends with a trailing slash, accepts both GET and POST, and where the client sends a POST request without the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

I did have the same problem once here what i did:
 the problem first come when a form is nested inside another one, and its method is ignored.

the solution is pretty simple:
Delete or close the superfluous and you're good to go .

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://forums.iis.net/t/1232018.aspx#2119314) helped me fix what was causing the issue for me.

If IIS Manager redirects the url, it changes a POST request to a GET request.
I had to change the server to *re-write* the url instead of *redirect* it.

I also had to enable *Application Request Routing* in IIS Manager.
I followed the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356301/error-404-4-the-resource-you-are-looking-for-does-not-have-a-handler-associated/51757737#51757737).

Answer (score 1):

(In my case, I found some causes.)

There can be many causes two of them are:

1. If forget to close the form tag.
2. Written post in a wrong way. i.e. It should be something like this:

   `<form action="index.php" method="post">`

If you write `method=post` , `method ="POST"`or `method ="Post"` then it will not work.
Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`method="post"` instead of `method=post`

Comment: It won't make a difference. The quotes are optional around simple HTML attribute values. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes

Answer (score 0):

May simply be that your user-agent is ignoring the form method because you haven't put quotes around the attribute.

Try:

```
 <form name="mistake" action="http://web-server:8888/WebApp/Email/Create" method="post">
```

Comment: No, it's not. Quotes don't matter around simple HTML attribute values. This is the 3rd time such as been suggested :) See http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes

Comment: It depends on the user-agent and the form of HTML. It's not a 'given'.

Comment: The UA is IE10. Any UA that doesn't accept simple (unquoted) attribute values is *not* a functioning HTML4/5 UA - even IE6 understands this syntax (which was kept/codified for backwards compatibility, not added as a cool HTML5 feature). And XHTML is *not* HTML.

Comment: The doctype wasn't specified, nor would it have been reasonable for me to assume the doctype was being applied correctly.

Comment: The doctype is mostly irrelevant in context. It's sure not XHTML code and the only reasonable alternative is that it is read as HTML5/4 - this is merely how the DOM is created from the markup and has no bearing on the various "modes". (Not to mention the UA was claimed to be IE10.)

Comment: "even IE6 understands this syntax" IE6 accepts all kind of rubbish. Lame argument. "And XHTML is not HTML" I don't assume people asking such questions on SO understand the semantic difference. "The doctype is mostly irrelevant in context" Might be irrelevant. I'm not that presumptuous to assume it's not.

Comment: None of your comments have been relevant or counter my claims. This answer is wrong.

Comment: The answer may be wrong, but it's not an unreasonable proposition given the limited facts presented. The fact that you're ascribing a bunch of facts to the OP that he/she never said just makes you presumptious.