# Error 404.4 The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it

Tags: node.js, iis-10

> HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found The resource you are looking for does not
>   have a handler associated with it.

```
web.config

<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />

                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}"  />
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I want to redirect `mywebsite.com` to  `http://localhost:3000`

- `mywebsite.com` is in `iis` and host file
- `http://localhost:3000` is a nodejs running the website
- I installed `Application Request Routing` and `url-rewrite`
- I set iusr permission on site folder
- The redirect works on my windows server 2016 but not on win 10

Answer (score 15):

You need to enable IIS to route the requests to nodejs.

First, download the Application Request Routing either by downloading on the IIS website or using the 'Web Platform Installer' in IIS Manager.

Next, on IIS Manager, select your server and under the IIS category, open Application Request Routing Cache.

On the right side of the screen, select 'Server Proxy Settings...' and tick enable proxy in the form.

After these steps, you may be able to connect to node correctly.

For reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two issues in the above code snippet, first of all the `</location>`
seems to be out of place.

Second thing is that you use <action type="Rewrite" while you probably mean <action type="Redirect"

Comment: the what seems to be out of place? Think you meant to put something there, I'm curious

Comment: HTML was stripped out added the ''